# Can we use "fall" in place of "fallen"?

Tags: word-meaning, learning

I was listening the song ["Guts over fear"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsUQJd6IrL4). It contains a line,

> Started thinking my name was fall.

I can't understand it. It would make sense if it were "fallen" not "fall". So my question is, Is the rapper using "fall" for "fallen" or the sentence means something else?

Comment: This question is based on a misunderstanding of a quote.

Comment: I hear _"Started thinking my name was 'fault.'"_

Comment: @Adam I usually do not get the accent of English, that is why I read the lyrics in that video. The lyrics in that video is wrong although.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [***lyrics***](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tvq5vzshti2koyepnjblrcynerq?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics) the line is:

> Started thinking my name was **fault**

I guess implying that various things were "his fault".

Comment: Link doesn't work.

Comment: I've checked the lyrics on other sites. You are right, it is "fault" on "fall".

Comment: Note the next two lines: "Cause any time things went wrong
I was the one who they would blame it on"